# Covert XML string output to XML file

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I am using XMWriter class for generating XML,but after generating my XML string I am not sure how to save it as an XML file.

.m code

```
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Miniparent"];
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Child"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:@"Text content for root element"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Child"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:@"Text content for root element"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];
```

Console output

```
<Miniparent>
<Child>Text content for root element</Child>
<Child>Text content for root element</Child>
<Child>Text content for root element</Child>
</Miniparent>
```

Comment: "formate as I want" what u want?

Comment: NSString > NSData > NSFileManager > file is my first thought on how to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to an NSString object

```
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
```

then save it to file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL succeed = [xml writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myXmlFile.xml"]
      atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!succeed){
    // Handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question as below ,and putting this code for other users

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//getting the path to document directory for the file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.xml"];

//checking to see of the file already exist
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
}
```